# Setting the values of a pandas df column based on ranges of values of another df column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df that looks like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3], 'b': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]})
```

I would like to create a columns 'c' that looks at values of 'a' to determine what operation to do to 'b' and display it in new column 'c'.

I have a solution that uses iterrow, however, my real df is large and iterrows is inefficient.

What I would like to do is do this operation in a vectorized form.
My 'slow' solution is:

```
df['c'] = 0
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['a'] <=-2:
        row['c'] = row['b']*np.sqrt(row[b]*row[a])
    if row['a'] > -2 and row['a'] < 2:
        row['c'] = np.log(row['b'])
    if row['a'] >= 2:
        row['c'] = row['b']**3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use  and .apply across multiple columns in a pandas (specifying axis=1) with a lambda function to get the job done. Not sure if the speed is ok. See this example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3], 'b': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]})

def func(a_, b_):
    if a_<=-2:
        return b_*(b_*a_)**0.5
    elif a_<2:
        return np.log(b_)
    else:
        return b_**3.

df['c'] = df[['a','b']].apply(lambda x: func(x[0], x[1]), axis=1)
```

Comment: This is a toy case, may def is a little more complex that what I have in the example, however, your solution works for the example and I could modify it to do what I want. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Use [np.select](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html). It's a vectorized operation.

```
conditions = [
    df['a'] <= -2,
    (df['a'] > -2) & (df['a'] < 2),
    df['a'] >= 2
]

values = [
    df['b'] * np.sqrt(df['b'] * df['a'])
    np.log(df['b']),
    df['b']**3
]

df['c'] = np.select(conditions, values, default=0)
```

Comment: Conditions displays ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Comment: See the updated answer. Be careful with `(` braces. It's `&` not `and`. @LuisMiguel

Answer (score 0):

```
df['c'] = df.apply(lambda x: my_func(x), 1)

def my_func(x):
   if x['a'] <= -2:
       return x['b']*np.sqrt(x[b]*x[a])

   # write other conditions as needed
```

The `df.apply` function iterates over each row of the dataframe and applies the function passed(i.e `lambda function`). The second argument is axis which is set to 1 which means it will iterate over rows and row values will be passed into the `lambda` function. By default it is 0, in this case it will iterate over columns.
Lastly, you need to return a value which will be set as column 'c' value.

Comment: Could you add more clarification?

Answer (score 0):

One method is to index by conditions and then operate on just those rows. Something like this:

```
df['c'] = np.nan
indices = [
    df['a'] <= -2,
    (df['a'] > -2) & (df['a'] < 2),
    df['a'] >= 2
]
ops = [
    lambda x: x['b'] * np.sqrt(x['b'] * x['a']),
    lambda x: np.log(x['b']),
    lambda x: x['b']**3
]
for ix, op in zip(indices, ops):
    df.loc[ix, 'c'] = op(df)
```